# CodeIgniter: Trouble removing "index.php" from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I have been trying to fix this for days and have tried the following tutorials:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456576/codeigniter-website-not-working-on-wamp-but-its-work-in-the-server) on stackoverflow
- [This](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/189852) from CI forums

And many many others.

None have worked.

*Here is my problem:*

Whenever I click the site link in WAMP localhost/ci/index.php/HomeController
It works fine.

If I omit the “index.php” from the url
(localhost/ci/HomeController),
however, it shows me the same folder list as on localhost.

This is my htaccess file in root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And in the config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

This still redirected me to WAMP home page.

I also uncommented this (in the httpd.conf file).

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

**Additional information:**

in my routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "HomeController";
```

My abbreviated file structure:
(located at C:\wamp\www)

- /ci

  - /application

    - /cache
    - /config
    - /controllers
    - /core
    - /errors
    - /helpers
    - /hooks
    - /languages
    - /libraries
    - /logs
    - /models
    - /third_party
    - /views
    - .htaccess
    - index.html
  - /assets
  - /system
  - .htaccess
  - index.php

Any help is appreciated. Sorry if there are already answers on this topic. None have worked for my project.

**Edit**:

If I try this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is the default htaccess I use for my projects to remove the index.php

`RewriteBase` (`/ci/`) and `RewriteRule` (`/ci/index.php`) should reference the base directory of your project. This is to say, is your project hosted at http://www.yoursite.com/ci/?

Also, if you are hosting your project on WAMP you need to enable htaccess in the config. To do this, click on the WAMP icon and choose Apache->Apache Modules->rewrite_module. Then restart all services.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work for me. I got a "Internal Server Error".

Comment: strange because I used this htaccess on my subfolder which is also named ci and it worked OK. Well I am sorry then I cant be of more help. If I get smh new I will edit this

Comment: Ah.. put this htaccess into ci folder so it will be located here: `ci/.htaccess`

Comment: That's where it already is... Are there any tests I can run to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Only three steps are require to remove index.php from url in Codeigniter in WAMP environment.

1) Create .htacess file in parallel to application holder and just copy past the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2) Change $config['index_page'] to blank in config.php in application folder as below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3) Enable “rewrite_module” of apache.

Restart your apache and its done.

Details : http://goo.gl/3jfW8f